# Cannot invoke @Remote interface in separate ear

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

This is a real newbie question but I would appreciate some help. I have looked in other questions but I haven't found a solution. Maybe I am overlooking something simple.

I am deploying an ear to jboss that has an ejb module:

- In the ejb jar is a single bean, MyBean which is @Stateless.
- The ejb jar also has a dependency on an api jar. In the api jar is a single @Remote interface, MyInterface.

This api jar is in the lib folder of the ejb.
MyBean implements MyInterface.
I deploy the ear, and this all goes ok. I am deploying it to jboss eap 6.3.0. So in theory this bean should be available to other ears & wars.

Then: I also have a war with a simple rest class to call the remote MyInterface.
(The idea is just to call a remote bean from a war deployed separately from the ear that has the bean).

This gives me the following error when I deploy the war:

> WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [MyInterface] with
>   qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private
>   com.test.rest.MessageRestService.myInterface]

The rest class is as follows:

```
package com.test.rest;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.test.MyInterface;

@Path("/message")
public class MessageRestService {

    @Inject
    private MyInterface myInterface;

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        final String result = myInterface.generateText(msg);
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have beans.xml in META-INF in both the ear and the ejb, and it is also in the war in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml.

I have also put bean-discovery-mode="all" in the beans.xml but no joy.
Also the bean MyBean (implementing the remote interface) has a no args constructor.

Also: I have the api jar with the interface and the ejb jar brought in as dependencies in the war. But it still gives this "unsatisfied dependencies" error...

any ideas?

thanks

Update: this is the MyInterface class:

```
package com.test;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface MyInterface {

    public String generateText(String text);

}
```

And MyBean:

```
package com.mycompany;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import com.test.MyInterface;

@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyInterface {

    public MyBean(){

    }

    public String generateText(String text) {
        return "Hello there! " + text;
    }

}
```

Bindings:

```
19:11:22,679 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named MyBean in deployment unit subdeployment "MavenEnterpriseApp-ejb.jar" of deployment "MavenEnterpriseApp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/MavenEnterpriseApp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavenEnterpriseApp-ejb/MyBean!com.test.MyInterface
    java:app/MavenEnterpriseApp-ejb/MyBean!com.test.MyInterface
    java:module/MyBean!com.test.MyInterface
    java:global/MavenEnterpriseApp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavenEnterpriseApp-ejb/MyBean
    java:app/MavenEnterpriseApp-ejb/MyBean
    java:module/MyBean
```

Comment: What happens if you inject with @EJB instead?

Comment: Yes that works. Why is that I can't use @ Inject here? Or is it standard that you use @ EJB to call a bean like this?

Comment: Also: I had hoped to be able to only bundle the interface with the war, and that java would resolve the implementation class. But when I try to remove the dependency on the implementation class, or even have the dependency as "provided", neither works.

Comment: Show the code for MyInterface and MyBean. The container should create a proxy stub so that calls through MyInterface are remoted to the EJB deployed in your EAR file. Your @EJB annotation may also need a "mappedName" parameter containing one of the global names that JBoss assigns to your MyBean when it deploys it. These names are typically listed in the console log.

Comment: Have now injected:  `@EJB(mappedName="java:global/MavenEnterpriseApp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavenEnterpriseApp-ejb/MyBean!com.test.MyInterface")
 private MyInterface myInterface;` but no joy, is there something else I need to do for the bean and the interface, specify mappedName on the bean maybe? Tried this also but no luck..

Comment: EDIT: I can get it if I do a `context.lookup("java:global/MavenEnterpriseApp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavenEnterpriseApp-ejb/MyBean!com.ciaran.test.MyInterface");` but is there a way to use @EJB?

Comment: I really expected that `mappedName` should work. You could also try `lookup="java:global/MavenEnterpriseApp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavenEnterpri‌​seApp-ejb/MyBean!com.test.MyInterface"`

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I'll also try making the rest class a servlet.  I have a feeling that it is not enabled for ejb dependency injection. Can't check it now but will try later

Comment: Ok, I got it to work! Thanks. I was switching between Local and Remote on the interface and that might have caused some problems. It worked with a lookup: @EJB(lookup=...). For mappedName do you have to put an annotation on the bean or the interface as well as at the injection point? The only other thing I was wondering was can you use @Inject to do this?